# How to test the kernel for kernel panics?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am testing the Linux Kernel on an embedded device and would like to find situations / scenarios in which Linux Kernel would issue panics.

Can you suggest some test steps (manual or code automated) to create Kernel panics?

Comment: If there were a reliable way to create kernel panics that *didn't* involve injecting panic-causing code into the kernel, I would hope that bug would be fixed at some point.

Comment: I used to unplug the storage with the device on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a variety of tools that you can use to try to crash your machine:

[crashme](http://packages.debian.org/sid/crashme) tries to execute random code; this is good for testing process lifecycle code.

[fsx](http://codemonkey.org.uk/projects/fsx/) is a tool to try to exercise the filesystem code extensively; it's good for testing drivers, block io and filesystem code.

The [Linux Test Project](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/) aims to create a large repository of kernel test cases; it might not be designed with *crashing* systems in particular, but it may go a long way towards helping you and your team keep everything working as planned. (Note that the LTP isn't *proscriptive* -- the kernel community doesn't treat their tests as anything important -- but the LTP team tries very hard to be *descriptive* about what the kernel does and doesn't do.)

If your device is network-connected, you can run [nmap](http://nmap.org/) against it, using a variety of scanning options: `-sV --version-all` will try to find versions of all services running (this can be stressful), `-O --osscan-guess` will try to determine the operating system by throwing strange network packets at the machine and guessing by responses what the output is.

The [nessus](http://www.nessus.org/download/) scanning tool also does version identification of running services; it may or may not offer any improvements over nmap, though.

You can also hand your device to users; they figure out the craziest things to do with software, they'll spot bugs you'd never even think to look for. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. But how do I understand the o/p of crashme and fsx ?  Is there any documentation on how to understand the output of these programs ?

Comment: Subprocess 59: Got signal 4 illegal instruction
Subprocess 59: Barfed
Subprocess 59: try 15, Badboy at 108472. 0x1A7B8
Subprocess 59: Got signal 11 segmentation violation
Subprocess 59: Barfed
Subprocess 59: try 16, Badboy at 110480. 0x1AF90
Subprocess 59: Got signal 4 illegal instruction
Subprocess 59: Barfed
Subprocess 59: try 17, Badboy at 112488. 0x1B768
Subprocess 59: Got signal 4 illegal instruction
Subprocess 59: Barfed
Subprocess 59: try 18, Badboy at 114496. 0x1BF40
Subprocess 59: Got signal 11 segmentation violation
Subprocess 59: Barfed

Comment: @abc, all those look like trying different mechanisms to crash the kernel; you probably only need to investigate the output when the kernel begins behaving badly -- the diagnostic messages are to help you figure out what specific sequence of instructions killed the kernel.

Answer (score 9):

You can try following key combination

<kbd>SysRq</kbd>  + <kbd>c</kbd>

or

> echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger

Comment: This is the best approach. Thanks. Here is more details: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-kdump-configuration-testing.html

Answer (score 1):

Crashme has been known to find unknown kernel panic situations, but it must be run in a potent way that creates a variety of signal exceptions handled within the process and a variety of process exit conditions.

The main purpose of the messages generated by Crashme is to determine if sufficiently interesting things are happening to indicate possible potency. For example, if the `mprotect` call is needed to allow memory allocated with `malloc` to be executed as instructions, and if you don't have the `mprotect` enabled in the source code crashme.c for your platform, then Crashme is impotent.

It seems that operating systems on x64 architectures tend to have execution turned off for data segments. Recently I have updated the crashme.c on http://crashme.codeplex.com/ to use `mprotect` in case of `__APPLE__` and tested it on a MacBook Pro running MAC OS X Lion. This is the first serious update to Crashme since 1994. Expect to see updated Centos and Freebsd support soon.